# URL Inepretation in Granite TIDE with flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, ria, graniteds

I did the presentation tier analysis of my application with HTTPWatch.In that I found there are request being made with followng URL,

```
https://hostname/path/graniteamf/amf
```

with each of these request taking morearound 2s.I am not able to interpret this URL to the actual problem.Is it because of the UI components being loaded or the method being called.

Would be happy to get any information on the same.

Cheers,
Dwarak

Comment: This looks like an Flex Remoting Gateway URL.  So, these are probably requests that your app is making to the server.  ServiceCapture will tell you the name of the method being called; and you can drill down into the details to get info on the arguments passed.  I don't know anything about HTTPWatch, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the actual string, or did you replace 'hostname' and 'path' with placeholders? What is defined in your services-config.xml file? Are the requests failing, too slow, or unexpected?

Best guess given the info you provided, it sounds like you may just need to update/fix services-config.xml. (Make sure you really want https -- if you're trying to use http that can cause an issue too.)

Comment: Yes,I replaced the hostname and path.The requests are not failing, but they are slow.